# Need to match 2 numbers from source

Tags: regex, preg-match

I want to get the first value of 8,222,567 and also another regex that will take the second value of 7,089. These digits are dynamic, so they change each time.

The second value starts daily over again from 0.

Is there anyone who could make me this regex?

```
<p>
    8,222,865 people have bought the game.
</p>
<p>
    In the last 24 hours, 7,087 people bought the game.
</p>
```

For the second regex I need to match what is *between* **hours,** and **people**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged `preg-match`, so we'll assume PHP and PCRE.  This is fairly easy using `([\d,]+)` capture groups:

```
/([\d,]+)\s+people\s+.*24 hours,\s+([\d,]+)\s+people.*/sm
```

- `^` = start of the string (removed after comments)
- `([\d,]+)` the string of digits and commas that make up the first number, captured in `()`
- `.+?` Non-greed set of any characters following the number up until...
- `hours,`  : ...the literal string hours followed by a comma
- `([\d,]+)` = Another `()` capture group for the second number
- `.*` = Everything else up to the end of the string.
- `/sm` The multi-line modifier and `s` "dotall" which makes the `.` match newlines

Note that this *doesn't* validate that the number is actually a real number, with the `,` thousands separator in the right place. It just looks for a string of digits and commas. So even something invalid like `99,,112345,` would match in that position. But if you don't expect your input to look like that, and *do* expect a *real* number to appear at the start of the string and after `hours,` this isn't a big deal.

To match a *valid* number you would need something more complex like

```
((?:\d{1,3},)(?:\d{3},)*(?:\d{1,3}))
```

And that still isn't even totally right, as it would match 123,456,1.

#### Quick test in PHP:

```
$pattern = '/([\d,]+)\s+people\s+.*24 hours,\s+([\d,]+)\s+people.*/sm';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => 8,222,865 people have bought the game.
</p>
<p>
    In the last 24 hours, 7,087 people bought the game.
</p>
    [1] => 8,222,865
    [2] => 7,087
)
```

Comment: @Sedoc94 Then take off the anchor `^` which forces the number to occur at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake. Can you please use the new html code to use this regex on? I really appreciate your thoroughly explained answer!

Comment: I think this code only works when the source is written on one line. If I try this on my html code above, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sedoc94 I have it sorted out now.  Needed the `/sm` modifiers